# WallpaperManager leaking memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am using `leakcanary` detect memory leaks on Android. First time using `WallpaperManager`. I don't know if you `recycle` or clean the `WallpaperManager` on destroy.

```kotlin
val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
wallpaperManager.setStream(file.inputStream())
```

I think these two lines of code are causing this issue, because if I comment these two lines the memory leak is not occuring.

```kotlin
private fun setWallpaper() {
    val dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!.absoluteFile
    val file = File("$dir${File.separator}wallpaper.jpg")
    val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
    wallpaperManager.setStream(file.inputStream())

    toast(getString(R.string.wallpaper_set_successfully))
}
```

[image: leakcanary result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `WallpaperManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());`

This definitely looks like a bug in AOSP and you should file a ticket, but in the meantime using the app context should avoid the leak.